# Why does user image shows up as a broken link in my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started learning Ruby on Rails and I am completely new to this.
After completing tutorial on rails at Progate, I have decided to make my own app by following the same steps (appropriate for my environment) as I did at Progate.
Right now I am at the point where I want the User profile image to show on details page and user index page, but I only see broken image link.
Here is code of my "User Controller"

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(
      name: params[:name],
      email: params[:email],
      image_name: "default_user.png"
    )
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You have signed up successfully"
      redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")
    else
      render("users/new")
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @user.name = params[:name]
    @user.email = params[:email]

    # Add code to save the image
    if params[:image]
      @user.image_name = "#{@user.id}.jpg"
      image = params[:image]
      File.binwrite("public/user_images/#{@user.image_name}", image.read)
    end
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your account has been updated successfully"
      redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")
    else
      render("users/edit")
    end
  end

end
```

I have tried to change image format and permission properties of image (no changes).Here is my index view file -

```
<div class="main users-index">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="users-heading">All Users</h1>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <div class="users-index-item">
        <!-- Paste the HTML here -->
        <div class="user-left">
          <!-- Add an <img> tag to display the profile image -->
          <img src="<%= "/user_images/#{user.image_name}" %>">
        </div>
        <div class="user-right">
          <%= link_to(user.name, "/users/#{user.id}") %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and show view file

```
<div class="main user-show">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="user">
      <!-- Add an <img> tag to display the profile image -->
      <img src="<%= "/user_images/#{@user.image_name}" %>">
      <h2><%= @user.name %></h2>
      <p><%= @user.email %></p>
      <%= link_to("Edit", "/users/#{@user.id}/edit") %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried re-writing same thing over and over. I have checked my migration db file and everything seems to be fine there.Checked image directory too. SCSS file is fine and it is completely same as the one I've used in tutorial.
However my SQlite Database Viewer gives me this -
[Sqlite db view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pIxS.png)

Comment: Do you know if the image is not found? Or if its downloading the image but not displaying it properly?

Comment: I think it is not found. When I inspect page source there is an error - ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: try to access your file in the browser like this "http://localhost:3000/user_images/img-name.jpg or png"

if you are able to get your image in the browser you will surely be able to access it.

i think here your issue is of .extention after the image name

Comment: If you inspect it, is the url path for the image matching where the image is located?  Likely it is not but inspecting it to see will show you (likely) what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the asset pipeline, save your image in the `app/assets/images` directory and instead of using an `<img></img>` HTML tag change it to this `<%= image_tag "image_name.file_extension %>`

Related links:

- [Asset pipeline: Links to assets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out, if I had already a user saved without image - default image wouldn't automatically show on his profile.
I had to edit his profile and upload an image  in order for it to show up.
I suppose, default image only applies to users that would be created after that method (add_image_name_to_users) was implemented.
Either way, thanks everyone for offering solutions!